# How large is a disk sector anyway?

Tags: stat, hard-drive, sector

So, since ages I have been told that hard disks (I am specifically interested in HDDs and not SSDs) write data in units of 512 bytes, sectors. But when I interrogate the folder with `stat .` then I get told that blocks are 4096 bytes. How do I find out the sector size for the HDD and not the filesystem?

```
$ stat .
  Plik: .
  rozmiar: 4096         bloków: 8          bloki I/O: 4096   katalog
Urządzenie: fd01h/64769d    inody: 58327220    dowiązań: 8
Dostęp: (0755/drwxr-xr-x)  Uid: ( 1000/arkadiusz)   Gid: ( 1000/arkadiusz)
Dostęp:      2021-12-21 18:53:44.275157484 +0100
Modyfikacja: 2021-12-16 23:35:35.206793831 +0100
Zmiana:      2021-12-16 23:35:35.206793831 +0100
Utworzenie:  2018-09-09 04:23:32.113656998 +0200
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disk_sector) clearly states that 512-byte sector is the normal,
unless we are talking about Advanced Format standard of 4K (4096 bytes).

As per comment: use `sudo fdisk -x /dev/sda` to get all the info you are looking for.

Comment: You did not answer my question.

Comment: Run this command on your system:
sudo fdisk -l /dev/sda 
(if sda is the HDD in question)